# Is there an algorithm to solve my case?

Tags: c#

I’m facing a bit of a problem in one of my projects and I’m hoping you guys could bring some clarity to the matter.

The case is like this; I’ve got a group of 12 people divided into 4 groups. This is the initial line-up in a series of 3 rounds.

My problem I this; How can I re-render these groups, for the two following rounds, so that the people in the groups not before have met?

I want the re-rendered groups to be unique, eg. Person 1 shall never in the next two rounds join a group with either Person 2 or Person 3. And if Person 1 forms a group with Person 4 and Person 5 in the second round, these persons shall also be excluded in the last round.

**Group 1**

Person 1, Person 2, Person 3

**Group 2**

Person 4, Person 5, Person 6

**Group 3**

Person 7, Person 8, Person 9

**Group 4**

Person 10, Person 11, Person 12

Comment: One possibility: [round-robin tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament),

Comment: @paulsm4: Yes, but round-robin tournaments are usually for two person/team matches, not three.  I am not aware of any published round-robin movement schedules for three-person matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (i = 0 to NrGroups-1) do // NrGroups = 4
{
   newGroup + (i+1) = Arr[i] + 
                      Arr[(i+(Arr.length/NrPersonsInGroup))%Arr.length] + 
                      Arr[(i+(Arr.length/NrPersonsInGroup+1))%Arr.length]; // NrPersonsInGroup = 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) algorithm. For more details on Combination like performance, etc check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n?lq=1) and for code samples with explanation, you can check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G#).
 
Your specific implementation is Combination of 12 people taking 3 at a time with no repetition. This gives you 220 possible groups.
One way of checking if the same two people have been in a group before is to keep a record of the groups that have been formed and check any new groups against the record to see if the two groups being compared have any two people in common.